# triggering custom action after component installed

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3.6

I have several features that I'm installing and I want to trigger a custom action after a certain feature installed. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not "after" a component is installed, "when" a component is being installed or when a component is already installed or being installed.  Same concept for a feature.  See the Windows Installer help topic [Conditional Statement Syntax (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368012%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You author these into the inner text of the Condition element.  Examples are:

[Examples of Conditional Statement Syntax (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368561%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)